# System.Data.Entity is not available

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I have added .Net Standard Library 2.0 and I have installed [EntityFramework 6.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) via NuGet Package manager, But unable to inherit `DbContext` in my class because System.Data.Entity is not available. What should I do to use [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)?

Comment: you need [.net standard 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/v6.4.0/src/NuGet/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.NuGet.nuspec#L12)

Answer (score 1):

As @magicandre1981 said, you need to upgrade to .NET Standard 2.1.

I hate all these hidden version incompatibilities! We had EntityFramework 6.2 running in a .NET Standard 2.0 project. Updating EF produced no version incompatibility warnings, even though if you look closely from EF 6.3+ it requires .NET Standard 2.1.

Edit: And the calling project is Framework 4.8, which does NOT support .NET Standard 2.1.  So it's back to EF 6.2 and .NET Standard 2.0 for me.